# How to prevent gradle from downloading SNAPSHOT jar

Tags: java, spring, gradle, build.gradle

I am using a dependency module-x which has may or may not have SNAPSHOT version of trivial/other dependencies. When I build the application I wanted to make sure that all the trivial/other dependencies are of release type and not SNAPSHOT as SNAPSHOT keeps changing.

build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.my-group-x:module-x:1.2'
}
```

it downloads a bunch of dependencies and it may have multiple dependencies which are of SNAPSHOT typed

```
module-y:2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
module-z:3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
module-k:2.7-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

How I can make sure it is rejected and not added to the application? Also i dont know the dependencies to exclude it specifically.

Answer (score 5):

You can exclude dependencies in build tools, see:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:excluding-transitive-deps

You can also configure the Maven repositories used in Gradle, see:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:repository-content-filtering 
Here is an example to use only release versions or only snapshot version:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.mycompany.com/releases"
        mavenContent {
            releasesOnly()
        }
    }
    maven {
        url "https://repo.mycompany.com/snapshots"
        mavenContent {
            snapshotsOnly()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if I don't know the dependencies to exclude which are having the SNAPSHOT version? sorry, my question doesn't cover that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `libs.versions.toml` you can dynamically check the content of the `libs` variable, in the `gradle.properties` add:

```
withSnapshot=true
```

Then in your `build.gradle.kts` (or custom plugin) add:

```
val withSnapshot: String by project
when (withSnapshot) {
    "true" -> {}
    else -> {
        val libs = project.extensions.getByType(VersionCatalogsExtension::class).named("libs")
        libs.libraryAliases
            .mapNotNull { libs.findLibrary(it).getOrNull()?.get() }
            .forEach {
                when (it.version?.lowercase()?.contains("snapshot")) {
                    true -> throw GradleException("dependency ${it.module}:${it.version} uses a snapshot version")
                    false -> {}
                    null -> throw GradleException("dependency ${it.module}:${it.version} has a null version")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Then try it by adding in your `libs.versions.toml`:

```
[versions]
toto = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
[libraries]
toto = { module = "toto:toto", version.ref = "toto" }
```

Then run with:

```
./gradlew clean build -PwithSnapshot=false
```

You should see in the error log:

```
> dependency toto:toto:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT uses a snapshot version
```

However it will not prevent snapshots from transitive dependencies...